How to force DWM to render server-side decoration (SSD) on all windows?
Question
Summarily, I'm asking how to force SSD, rather than allow certain windows to instruct DWM to allow them to render CSD for themselves. Is this possible using the default DWM window manager in Windows 11?
Examples

CSD
From Windows 7 to 11, CSD encapsulates:

A new window border type managed by DWM in Windows 10 to 11. This replaced whatever component renders the previous ones - as demonstrated when dwm.exe is killed.
If you still aren't ware of which I refer to, these are the 1 logical pixel-wide ones, instead those of user-configurable width, visible in Windows 8.1 and below (including Aero and Classic).

The ability (especially for XAML-based applications, like those which utilize UWP and WinUI in Windows 8 to 11) to render custom content atop / instead of the standard title bar, like Steam and the Epic Games Store do.



SSD
As an example of SSD, I'll use KDE Plasma 5.27+, which has included the same kind of window border. This Quora answer of mine explains that forcing it to render (under X11) is possible the default WM (KWin)'s noborderrule=2 window rule, so I expect that DWM possesses similar capabilities, considering its age (and consequent versatility).
You can see this demonstrated in the attachments of this Bugzilla ticket:

Absent border and titlebar




Absent border, but present titlebar




Present border and titlebar







Rationale
The new window border is satisfactory to me, because it allows me to easily ascertain where a window begins and ends. Consequently, I don't want to disable them like this SU answer, nor render the old ones, like this SU answer.
However, this isn't yet adequate, because any window which defines its own CSD entirely, like this example project on GitHub (but unlike XAML-based WinUI applications, or Firefox) don't render them. You've probably seen this in the hideous Windows 8-style dialogs still scattered throughout the OS.
Corroborative Requests

Negative

github.com/mpv-player/mpv/issues/3646#issuecomment-297066378 (per reddit.com/r/linux/comments/7v8e9q/comment/dtq8v2e)
news.ycombinator.com/item?id=33162116
github.com/jellyfin/jellyfin-media-player/issues/40#issuecomment-821773023
news.ycombinator.com/item?id=34269299
forums.factorio.com/viewtopic.php?p=607328#p607328
bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=452240#c0
github.com/twinbasic/twinbasic/issues/1713


Neutral

github.com/kovidgoyal/kitty/issues/3284#issuecomment-822539154
betaarchive.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=452117#p452117
tenforums.com/customization/153759-windows-basic-style-win7-non-aero-theme-windows-10-a-2.html#post2169172
winclassic.net/thread/911/current-method-recent-win10-disable?page=1&scrollTo=7417
reddit.com/r/kde/comments/p5zlju




What is SSD in this context? I presume it is not "Solid State Drive".

@music2myear, "server-side decoration", as opposed to CSD. Unfortunately, there's not a Wikipedia page for it (despite the aforereferenced one for its counterpart existing), but it's basically the window manager drawing the window decorations. Instead of CSD, where the window itself draws the window decorations despite integrating with the window manager.

Giacomo, I'll incorporate /revisions/1850632/12, but /11 is not an improvement - there's no reason to lengthen that section by displaying the URI schemas.

When It Cannot Be Enabled

GNOME 40's Mutter
Unfortunately, the answer to this appears to be specific to the operating system, window manager, display server, compositor, and the relevant versions thereof. Speficially, using the Mutter all-in-one display server, window manager, and compositor, this is currently impossible due to its deliberate lack of support for the Wayland protocol's XDG-Decoration extension (which provides SSD):

There are no plans to support server side decorations under Wayland, and it'd be a step backward from the path we are aiming for with Wayland. So given that, I'm going to close this one as a wont-fix.


KDE Plasma 6's Kwin
Additionally, for alternatives, the situation is more complex. Specifically, for KWin's all-in-one Wayland implementation, this functionality is (for now) deliberately unavailable. However, when using KWin merely as a window manager, with the standard XOrg 11 package acting as the display server and compositor (per bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=476996#c14).

Windows 10 and 11's dwm.exe
The rendering pipeline on Windows is more complex than on Linux-based OSes, because it's less standardised. dwm.exe provides APIs for XAML (UWP and/or WinUI2)-based applications, whereas older technologies (like VB6) may go through significantly lower-level implementations, like GDI.
In essence, this means that applications built using technologies that support falling back to older window decorations (like Windows <= 8's "Aero", or the Windows NT "Classic" fallback) requires the user to disable dwm.exe and prevent the OS knowing about this to initialize a fallback to the aforementioned window decoration styles. Additionally, this also means that applications which intrinsically rely upon dwm.exe's CSD functionality shall fail to render whatsoever (like UWP/WinUI applications).


When It Can

Kwin
KWin's implementation can be activated as an "override" using the noborderrule=2 .ini/.desktop-format statement in a .KWinRules file, when imported into, and activated by, kcmshell6 kcm_kwinrules.

Windows 10+
Windows 10 and 11 are surprisingly similar to KWin in this respect. The undermentioned script that I've devised by using the information aforereferenced in the question's bibliography should ensure that the window decorations always render.
#!/usr/bin/env pwsh
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator
#Requires -PSEdition 'Core'
#Requires -Version 7.4

If ([OperatingSystem]::IsWindows() -Eq $True) {

   # 1. Replace `dwm.exe` with `rundll32.exe`.
   $ProcessPath = "$Env:SystemDrive\Windows\System32\dwm.exe"
   if (Test-Path $ProcessPath) {
       Rename-Item $ProcessPath 'dwm.exe.bak'
       New-Item -Path "$Env:SystemDrive\Windows\System32" -Name 'rundll32.exe' -ItemType 'File' -Force
   }

   # 2. Rename `Windows.UI.Logon.dll`.
   $LogonDLLPath = "$Env:SystemDrive\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.Logon.dll"
   if (Test-Path $LogonDLLPath) {
       Rename-Item $LogonDLLPath "Windows.UI.Logon.dll.bak"
   }

   # 3. Rename `$Env:SystemDrive\Windows\SystemApps` to something else.
   $SystemAppsPath = "$Env:SystemDrive\Windows\SystemApps"
   if (Test-Path $SystemAppsPath) {
       Rename-Item $SystemAppsPath "$SystemAppsPath.bak"
   }

   # 4. Restart the computer.
   Restart-Computer

}

Else { Exit 1 }

However, this shall render explorer.exe's shell implementation (primarily sihost2.exe, which is responsible for the taskbar) and all UWP applications (rendered via XAML by dwm.exe) completely unusable.
An example of this is available at youtube.com/watch?v=1iXfUThaQ1Q.



Giacomo, https://superuser.com/revisions/1863156/5 is incorrect! This is PowerShell Core 7 code, not bash code. Read the preprocessor statements, at least.
